# IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow, despite checking for empty cursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have the following code: `result` is the cursor.

```
    if (result.getCount() == 1 && result.getColumnCount() > 0) {
        result.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = result.getColumnIndex(TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN);
        long time = currentTimeMilliMinutes();
        sumTotal = time - result.getLong(columnIndex);
    }
```

So, even though I'm checking for rows and columns, it throws the error in the title.  I don't know what else I should be doing to prevent this error.  The cursor should only have 1 row, 1 column, value `long`, I have checked the sql statement via `adb` and it seems to be correct.

EDIT:

Here is the query:

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX("+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN+
            ") FROM "+TrackerContract.WorkLog.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_FDP_BEGIN+
            "=(SELECT MAX("+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_FDP_BEGIN+") FROM "+TrackerContract.WorkLog.TABLE_NAME+");", 
            null);
```

When I enter the same sql via adb, I get the correct long value as the only return value (1 row, 1 col).  Here is the actual SQL statement, incase my encoding didn't go correctly.  I plan on refactoring this to use the parameterized query method rather than raw sql, but for now I am just making sure it works, and using the raw statements is easier for me.

```
select max(blockTimeEnd) from WorkLog where dutyDayStart=(select max(dutyDayStart) from WorkLog);
```

The Stack Trace:

```
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at com.berrmal.timetracker.MainActivity.currentRest(MainActivity.java:503)
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at com.berrmal.timetracker.MainActivity.updateTimeTotals(MainActivity.java:567)
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at com.berrmal.timetracker.MainActivity.populateViews(MainActivity.java:187)
12-25 16:55:00.477: E/AndroidRuntime(32708):    at com.berrmal.timetracker.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:183)
```

Edit 2:
did some logging/debugging, the column name in the cursor returned is `max(blockTimeEnd)` where it should be `blockTimeEnd`.  This is clearly the error.

Comment: Post error log and the query or complete method, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, `result.getColumnIndex(TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN)` returns -1 as it cannot find the column. From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) on `getColumnIndex`:

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.

Make sure that `TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN` is a proper column name.

UPDATE:

As you're using `SELECT MAX(blockTimeEnd)`, the returned column name is not `blockTimeEnd`. Change the select part of your query to use the alias `SELECT MAX(blockTimeEnd) AS blockTimeEnd` or in case of using constants:

```
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX("+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN+
        ") AS " + TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN + " FROM "+TrackerContract.WorkLog.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_FDP_BEGIN+
        "=(SELECT MAX("+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_FDP_BEGIN+") FROM "+TrackerContract.WorkLog.TABLE_NAME+");", 
        null);
```

Alternatively, read the column by number in your code as you know you have only 1 returned:

```
if (result.getCount() == 1 && result.getColumnCount() > 0) {
    result.moveToFirst();
    long time = currentTimeMilliMinutes();
    sumTotal = time - result.getLong(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't understand why the code tries to access columnIndex -1, the if statement checks if the cursor has exactly 1 row and a column count > 0, so if the column count is -1 that line should not be executed, right?

Comment: See my update. The problem is that if you use an aggregate function, the returned column name is different. See my update for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: when using the sql statement `SELECT max(column) FROM table WHERE..."` it appears the returned column name is `max(column)`, not `column`.

Maybe this is common knowledge, I'm an SQL beginner, but this was not clear to me after reading the documentation of the max() function.

I changed the line

```
if (result.getCount() == 1 && 
            (columnIndex = result.getColumnIndex(TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN)) >= 0) {
```

to

```
if (result.getCount() == 1 && 
            (columnIndex = result.getColumnIndex("max("+TrackerContract.WorkLog.COLUMN_BLOCK_IN + ")")) >= 0) {
```

and the function now works as designed.

Since I know, by design, my query should only return 1 row 1 column, I could also just select column index 0 without checking the name.